# Removal of object from array depending on object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I am having a few problem with my JavaScript game. I have 3 enemies on the screen and they can be shot at by the controllable player. The problem is that when you kill certain enemies they are removed, but sometimes other ones are too.

The following code is fed these variables (x, y and angle may vary):

**enemys** - an array of objects:

```
{
  x: 646,
  y: 343,
  angle: 137,
  speed: 0,
  canSeePlayer: 0,
  health: 10,
  fireCooldown: 10
}
```

The code:

```
enemys.forEach(function(enemy) {
    var enemyIndex = enemys.indexOf(enemy);
    if (enemys[enemyIndex].health <= 0) {
        enemys.splice(enemy, 1);
    }
});
```

Is it possible to remove a object from an array based on value any easier way?

Comment: from the documentation, splice needs an index, not an object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice
use: enemys.splice(enemyIndex, 1);

Comment: Wow, great thanks. I really need to read the documentation carefully

Comment: I am making a proper answer, one that will help make this even faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, array.splice() needs an index, not an object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

So you COULD use:

`enemys.splice(enemyIndex, 1);`

However, there IS a better way... Try this:

```
function IsDead( enemy ) {
    if( enemy.health <= 0 ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function RemoveDead( enemys ) {
    var deadEnemies = enemys.find( IsDead );
    for( enemy in deadEnemies ) {
        enemys.slice( enemys.indexOf( enemy ), 1 );
    }
}
```

Now just run the code:

```
RemoveDead( enemys );
```

Here is the new "array.find()" function documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Now some reasons why to do this:

1. It's reusable! - Two functions that are easy to use any time any where.
2. It's readable! - At first glance, we've no idea what that `enemys.forEach(....)` does. `RemoveDead()` is really plain English and it takes less than a second to know what you are doing.
3. It's clean! - Maybe redundant, but when you write 1000s of lines of code, this goes a LONG way!

"This has more code" - Yes it does. But look at how reusable the code is. "IsDead()" can be called on any enemy object at any time. It's very handy! (and you probably already have one)

I would highly advise naming these functions to pertain to the object class you use for enemy. If the enemy object class is of type: "Sprite" or "Enemy" then use "IsSpriteDead" or "IsEnemyDead" and "RemoveDeadSprites" or "RemoveDeadEnemies" (notice plural of enemy is enemies). The reason why we want to do this is because if you have an `Enemy` type object and a `Friend` type object but they don't both have a "health" variable, you might accidentally call `RemoveDead()` with the `Friends` array as a parameter - which won't work and you might not get an easy to understand error. But if the function is cleverly named `RemoveDeadEnemies()` you'll remember this only works on `Enemy` type objects. I know this is elementary, but it really helps! :)

One last thing... you CAN make this better if you prototype a new array object and change `RemoveDead( enemys );` to `enemys.removeDead()`

Food for thought. :)

Edit:

MarkE pointed out an even better way to do this which he deserves credit for:

Let's add an `isDead()` method to your `Enemy` object (assumed above).

```
{
  x: 646,
  y: 343,
  angle: 137,
  speed: 0,
  canSeePlayer: 0,
  health: 10,
  fireCooldown: 10,
  isDead: function() {
    return this.health<=0;
  }
}
```

Now we remove the `IsDead()` function above and modify the `RemoveDead()` function I mentioned to this:

```
function RemoveDead( enemys ) {
    var deadEnemies = enemys.find( function(enemy){ return enemy.isDead(); } );
    for( enemy in deadEnemies ) {
        enemys.slice( enemys.indexOf( enemy ), 1 );
    }
}
```

Notice now the `Enemy` object itself determines if it is dead. HUGE props to MarkE for this BECAUSE what if there is another factor we want to consider? Perhaps later an `Enemy` can have a "invincible" property. You would have to find and modify all the death code. But if used a property of the `Enemy` object, we could simply change the code there to:

```
isDead: function() {
    return (this.health<=0 && !this.invincible);
}
```

And that's all there is to it. MarkE also pointed out that using the `isDead()` property, you can easily just ignore the dead enemies and reuse them later.

Thanks MarkE! :)

Comment: Totally agree with this! I don't know what his code does, so i didn't add that in. But if I were writing this, I would definitely add this in.

Comment: @markE I added some of your suggestions into my post, hope that's alright. :)